# how to read dynamic values passed from jmeter from a text file in java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, jmeter

I'm performing load testing on my APIs using Jmeter. I'm making an Http Request and the response of that Http Request is passed as part of request body to my 2nd Http Request. There, I'm passing the dynamic values from a text file as follows :-
Obj.txt

```
"Details": {
    "Start": "2019-08-28T11:39:57.153",
    "Expiry": "2020-08-28T11:39:57.153",
    "Accounts": [
      {
        "accType": "SAVINGS",
        "ReferenceNumber": "${RefNumber}",
        "AccNumber": "${AccNumber}"
      }
    ]
}
```

This json object is read in my java program. I'm calculating a signature for that json object as follows :-

```
  public static String signConsent() throws Exception{

        String objDetail = loadDetailsObject();

        String keysJson = "Random String";

        JsonWebKeySet jsonWebKeySet = new JsonWebKeySet(keysJson);

        String signature = sign(objDetail, jsonWebKeySet);

        return signature;
    }
```

How do I read dynamic values from a text file. I'm loading the textfile using `loadDetailsObject` function as follows :-

```
public static String loadDetailsObject()  {
        String details = "";
        try {
            consentDetails =  FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("Obj.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Erorr\n", e);
        }
        return details;
    }
```

The `RefNumber` and `AccNumber` will change each time and the signature accordingly will change. How do I read these dynamic values in java from a .txt file?

Comment: *"How do I read dynamic values from a text file."*  - Are you asking how to read a  JSON file?  A non-JSON text file?  Your question is unclear.

Comment: @StephenC I've updated the question. Please check now.

Comment: You need to decide which format you are using.  You are not using both.

Comment: @StephenC Please check now.

Comment: And what is the **format** of the text file?  You cannot read information from a file unless you know what the file format is.  Show us an example of the text file you are intending to read.

Comment: @StephenC The text file is the same as mentioned above in `Obj.txt`

Comment: 1)  That is JSON.  2) It doesn't contain the values of "${RefNumber}" and "${AccNumber}".  Those of placeholders of some kind. You are really not making a lot of sense here ....

Comment: Try reading this Q&A and see if it answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206125/discussion-between-cyberman123-and-stephen-c).

Answer (score 0):

Your "java program" doesn't know anything about [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html), I would recommend moving your signature code into [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) like:

1. In the HTTP Request sampler's "Body data" use the [__eval() and __FileToString() functions combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables/) to read file and at the same time evaluate all nested variables:

   ```
   ${__eval(${__FileToString(Obj.txt,,)})}
   ```

   [image]
2. In the JSR223 PreProcessor use the following code:

   ```
   String objDetail = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue()
   ```

   [image]